# Everpad on Ubuntu connected to Evernote, but no messages

Tags: 14.04, evernote, everpad

I have installed everpad on Ubuntu 14 with command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install everpad
```

When I run Everpad for first time I have Icon on the top of the screen like shown in picture:
[image]

I press **Settings and Management** and authorise **Evernote**  account:
[image]

Then I run Everpad second time and have window without my messages that was created in **Evernote** account. Looks like Everpad not synchronise messages with my PC:

[image]

How to solve this problem? Where are my notes?

Comment: Try this: shut down Everpad, move your `~/.everpad` folder to something like `~/.everpad-backup`, and restart Everpad.

Comment: this did not helped, I got the same situation

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you didn't kill all the processes (hint: everpad-provider).

Assuming you don't need to backup your notes (if you do, please do that before-hand), try this:

```
#close everpad
rm -rf ~/.everpad/ ~/.config/everpad/
killall everpad-provider
```

Then restart everpad. You shouldn't need do re-authorize.